# Sidekiq: configure exponential backoff for all workers

Tags: sidekiq

By default Sidekiq will retry jobs 25 times with an exponential backoff, I am trying to change the configuration for both the default retry count and the default exponential backoff for all workers.

 I see that you can change both of them at the class level with

sidekiq_options :retry 
 and 
 sidekiq_retry_in

```
class WorkerWithCustomRetry
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options :retry => 5

  sidekiq_retry_in do |count|
    10 * (count + 1) # (i.e. 10, 20, 30, 40)
  end

  def perform(...)
  end
end
```

I would like to change these defaults for the application as a whole. Not add the overrides to every class. 
I found out how to change the default max retries using

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.server_middleware do |chain|
    chain.add Sidekiq::Middleware::Server::RetryJobs, :max_retries => 5
  end
end
```

However I cannot find any examples of how to change the exponential backoff globally.

 Is this possible and if so how?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The middleware configuration doesn't support that.

Two options. One would be to extend the `Server::RetryJobs` middleware and override `def seconds_to_delay` there. Then use your customized middleware instead of the `Server::RetryJobs` that comes out of the box.

Another solution would be to have all your workers include `WorkerWithCustomRetry` instead of `Sidekiq::Worker`. Basically, make a wrapper around the Sidekiq default worker that is just for your app. I slightly prefer this second option because it works with Sidekiq's public interface rather than redefining a `private` method from the middleware, which could change anytime without notice.

Answer (score 1):

Change this in your initializer, e.g.:

```
Sidekiq::DEFAULT_WORKER_OPTIONS['retry'] = 5
```

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/lib/sidekiq.rb#L36

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Is there a way to set the exponential backoff in a similar manner?

Comment: I would monkey patch this method: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/retry_jobs.rb#L177

Comment: Things have changed in 7 years. Looks defaults are an instance variable now instead of a constant: https://github.com/sidekiq/sidekiq/blob/962797d1c424e9a8180dd2e9d0886f5b2e7cdd01/lib/sidekiq.rb#L85